# Name for a logical fallacy: confusing measures in argumentation

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, fallacies

I have encountered a line of reasoning in my research which seems to be [fallacious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy).

An example is if you wanted to know something about the general health of an individual, you could measure many different aspects of the individual. You might measure the individual's blood pressure, or you might count the number of cigarettes they smoke each week. Although both of these quantities tell you something about the general health of the individual, and the quantities themselves might be related in complex ways, an individual's blood pressure is not the same thing as the number of cigarettes they smoke each day.

More technically, in ecology, the concepts of both [niche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecological_niche) and [resource selection function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_selection_function) (RSF) tell us something about what conditions and resources are important to a species. However, under Hutchinson's (1957) definition the niche is a [geometric object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_shape) (i.e. think of a polygon in two dimensions), while a resource selection function describes behavior and is an index (single number, [scalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy)) that describes the proportion of used resources relative to the proportion of available resources. Both tell us something about how a species uses resources, but estimating an RSF is not the same as estimating a niche, and vise versa.

**If one has an argument and the premises confuse the nature of measures, would this be a logical fallacy, and if so is there a name for it? Please provide sources.**

Hutchinson, G. E. (1957). Cold spring harbor symposium on quantitative biology. Concluding remarks, 22, 415-427.

Comment: Maybe [Correlation does not imply causation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation) ?

Comment: This is called [conflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation):"*the practice of treating two distinct concepts as if they were one, which produces errors or misunderstandings*".

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.

Comment: I think Conifold is right that this is an example of conflation, but I was hoping there was a name for this specific form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say a niche is a "geometric object"? It's true that the word "niche" comes from a geometrical space in architecture, but that's just a metaphor, do ecologists actually define ecological niches in any geometric way?

Comment: @Hypnosifl, that is a very good question. Unfortunately, there is no way to adequately answer it in a comment. Considering there is a peer-reviewed paper titled "I can't define the niche but I know it when I see it" (Godsoe 2009), this should not be surprising. I suggest heading over to the Biology Stack Exchange site for an explanation.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - The most commonly used definition of the niche comes from Hutchinson (1957). Here, H. defines the niche as a n-dimensional "hypervolume ..., every point in which corresponds to a state of the environment which would permit the species ... to exist indefinitely". In this sense, the niche is an object in n-dimensional environmental space and thus has geometric properties in the same way that circles have geometric properties in 2D space. As you can see, the ecological definition has diverged from the architectural definition.

Comment: @ETam - The concept of the niche has been around for over 100 years. As a central concept in ecology, there are alternative definitions as well as significant misunderstandings, oversimplifications, and disagreements over the definition of the niche, what they imply, and how they can be interpreted. Above, I refer to Hutchinson's 1957 definition, which is the mostly commonly referenced concept and the one described in any introductory textbook on ecology. I have edited my answer above to clarify this.

Comment: @BenCarlson - I see what you mean, but note that for any system whose state is described by n variables, you're free to represent the state as a point in an n-dimensional space, but this is just a matter of mathematical convenience, here it'd be a way of talking about which possible combinations of values of the environmental variables would "permit the species ... to exist indefinitely" and which wouldn't. And you can have multivariable functions that take values of multiple variables x,y,z,... as input and return the value of a single variable v as output, couldn't that be applied here?

Comment: I would add that part of the difficulty answering your question is that you haven't really explained what you mean by "confusing measures", or how this applies to the two measures you mention of a niche vs. a resource selection function--are you saying it's a fallacy to believe the resource selection function might itself be estimated from knowledge of the niche, or are you talking about people who "confuse" them by literally saying "niche" when they mean "resource selection function" or vice versa, or are you talking about a different form of confusion?

Comment: Are you looking for the Fallacy of Four Terms?

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**

As Conifold has pointed out in the comments, if two numbers are referenced in such a way that they confuse underlying concepts, then a [conflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflation) occurs. If those numbers are conceptually very closely related, but the meaning is such that the subtle distinction between them is missed, it may be an [equivocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation). Lastly, if numbers are used in such a way they poorly represent the central measure of a population, they may be a [hasty generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulty_generalization#Hasty_generalization) of some sort. Informal fallacies are highly context-dependent.

**Long Answer**

[Natural Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language) is complicated and often we use [synonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym), [paraphrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraphrase) for simplicity, or draw subtle distinctions with the [connotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation). In short, [polysemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) inheres to natural language like white to processed rice. This tends to cause problems in [informal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Informal_logic), where the [truth values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth-conditional_semantics) of one's [propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proposition) are highly sensitive to subtle differences in [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics). In fact, two numbers or measures can be conflated in many ways, not only by their essence, but by the mathematical relations they seek to fulfill, and this is a topic usually covered in [measurement theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/measurement-science/) or specifically within a mathematical field such as statistics which has more specific fallacies such as [sampling bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_bias).

Per WP:

> Conflation is the merging of two or more sets of information, texts, ideas, opinions, etc., into one, often in error... In logic, it is the practice of treating **two distinct concepts as if they were one** (emphasis mine), which produces errors or misunderstandings as a fusion of distinct subjects tends to obscure analysis of relationships which are emphasized by contrasts.[8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polysemy) However, if the distinctions between the two concepts appear to be superficial, intentional conflation may be desirable for the sake of conciseness and recall.

So, if one (ab)uses logic and arrives at a conclusion where two unrelated concepts are at play both with the special measure, it is conflation. That's different from equivocation. Again, WP:

> In logic, equivocation ('calling two different things by the same name') is an informal fallacy resulting from the use of a particular word/expression in multiple senses within an argument.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation)

A good example of that might be the use of two numbers both of which are [averages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average). As you probably know, there are many measures of central tendency.

Lastly, if the wrong numbers are used specifically within the context of making inferences about populations, it's possible those numbers can be abused in hasty generalization. Let's say someone invokes one measure in the context of describing a sample, but that number is irrelevant to drawing an inference about the population for whatever reason, then any conclusion reached would be unwarranted.

One should also bear in mind that from a logic perspective, the misuse and confusion of numbers cannot only affect the [validity or strength of the argument, but the soundness and cogency of propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning#Validity_and_soundness) depending on the effect on their truth-values (binary, multivalued, or infinite). That is to say, that a bad [predication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predication_(philosophy)) can occur in the proposition itself making the premise unsound or weak leading to an unsound or uncogent conclusion.

**Appendix:**

> This is called conflation:"the practice of treating two distinct concepts as if they were one, which produces errors or misunderstandings". – Conifold

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I think you are right that the scenario is a form of conflation. However, since there can be many underlying reasons for conflation, I was hoping there was a name for the specific form of conflation that I described above. Your example of different measurements of central tendency is a good one (continued in next comment).

Comment: (continued from above) I think you might also describe the scenario in terms of set notation: if A is a proper subset of C, and if B is a proper subset of C, this does not mean that A = B. I was hoping there was a formal name for this type of logical error, but perhaps it just falls under the more general error of conflation.

Comment: Another example might be a modified version of the "Map-territory relation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation. Say I had a map that describes a territory, and a text description of the territory. Both describe the territory but this does not mean that the map and the text description are the same thing. They have overlapping information but also some unique information and the representation of that information is different.

Comment: @BenCarlson After a quick scan of your follow-up, the [fallacy of the undistributed middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_the_undistributed_middle) comes to mind which is close. I love Korzybski's quotation (with the same measure of my disdain for Platonic forms), so let me reread your question and clarification and it give it some thought.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to be confused. Both concepts seem well-defined:

1. Niche: Nothing in your post indicates that niche is quantified. I'd say they are specific domains in the envirnoment like e.g. streams, trees, marsh, forests, lakes, caves, deserts, etc.
2. Resource Selection Function (RSF): RSF is *mathematically defined*, as the portion/fraction of available resources that is used.

I'm no ecologist, but can we say that a plant that grows in marshes is *healthier/unhealtheir* than one that calls deserts its home?

RSF too seems a rather poor choice to measure health of living organisms ... unless *overpopulation* is an illness or *diminishing food reserves* is disease marker, *ecologically*.

---

Anyway, the error here is to mistake *two* different things for *one*. I haven't come across a specific name for this fallacy so we're in luck. Would you mind if I named it *Ben Carlson Fallacy* (after the discoverer). Technically it's a *false (logical) equivalence* (thinking niche *implies & is implied* by RSF i.e. Niche = RSF). In psychiatry there's a condition called *Fregoli delusion* (believing **2** different persons are **1** person). I move to call this fallacy  *the Fregoli Fallacy* if you decline the offer to have the fallacy named after you.